# how to uninstall table associated with module for drupal 8

Tags: 8, configuration

I uninstalled drupal 8 migrate_example module but i still see the fields associated with migrate example module. How to remove it.

Comment: Have you tried running the cron a few times?

Comment: @FonsVandamme yes i did ! but i can still see the field associated with migrate example module

Comment: What field? migrate.module currently doesn't remove mapping tables, that's a core issue